# How to upload an image using image url from web in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, upload

I have a page , I need to Add a Picture from the web using it's URL and display it in my page same as the below image using Jquery or Javascript.

[image]

Comment: And what's the question and where is the code that failed you after having spent few hours doing it?

Comment: enchine marre.. surukke mool points ijind yaan sayyond ulle.. eer kuda down vote malthondullar..

Comment: do this by using any jquery plugin.. You can find it here... http://www.bestfreewebresources.com/20-awesome-jquery-file-uploader-plugins

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a textbox where you can enter the url for the image and a button to attach an event.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button"),
    input = document.getElementById("input"),
    image = document.getElementById("image"),
    src;

// button click event
button.onclick = function(){
  // in case you want to use somewhere else
  src = input.value;

  // set the image src to the input value
  image.src = src;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text"/>
<button id="button">click me</button>
<img id="image" height="200px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

- It just updates the image 'src'  attibute  and shows the image. and which is not saved ,and  its not performing like input type ='file'.